# R:Creating container to store data in a function

Tags: r, function, containers

I am trying to write a function that reads a vector of numbers element wise and then storing them into a container. This is meant as a practice before I code something with if conditions.

My approach has failed so far, as the function returns a null statement, instead of what I wanted. I tried writing it in script form and it it worked, but somehow it malfunctioned when written as a function.

Here's the code I used.

```
amieven<-function(x){
         flag<-numeric()
         for(i in 1:length(x)){
                    flag[i]=x[i]
    }
}
```

The script version that worked fine looks like this:

```
flag<-numeric()
      for (i in 1:length(x))
      flag[i]=x[i]
```

Comment: Your function seems to be a very inefficient way of doing `as.numeric(x)`? What are you actually trying to achieve? Also, there is no data structure "container" in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your goal is to return the container called `flag`, then you simply need to specify `flag` as the return value.

```
amieven<-function(x){
  flag<-numeric()
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    flag[i]=x[i]
  }
  return(flag)
}
```

or simply

```
amieven<-function(x){
  flag<-numeric()
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    flag[i]=x[i]
  }
  flag
}
```